# Completely stuck trying to get accurate CLS measurement in a web metrics JS function

Tags: javascript

Relatively new to JS and tasked to output some web metrics in variables from a function.

I currently have everything working below *except* the CLS:

```
var sampleTiming = window.performance.timing.navigationStart
console.log('Sample Timing:', sampleTiming)

var time = window.performance.timing;
if (time) {
    var dns = time.domainLookupEnd - time.domainLookupStart;
    var tcp = time.connectEnd - time.connectStart;
    var ssl = time.requestStart - time.secureConnectionStart;
    var firstByte = time.responseStart - time.navigationStart; 
    var onload = time.loadEventEnd - time.loadEventStart;   
    var request = time.responseStart - time.requestStart;
    var load = time.loadEventEnd - time.loadEventStart;
    var redirect = time.redirectEnd - time.redirectStart;
    var basepage = time.responseEnd - time.navigationStart
}

//Retrieve first browser-returned LCP entry
var firstLCP;
new PerformanceObserver((entryList) => {
    firstLCP = entryList.getEntries()[0].startTime;
}).observe({type: 'largest-contentful-paint', buffered: true});


//Retrieve browser-returned FCP entry
var fcp;

new PerformanceObserver((entryList) => {
  for (const entry of entryList.getEntriesByName('first-contentful-paint')) {
    fcp = entry.startTime;
  }
}).observe({type: 'paint', buffered: true});


//Retrieve browser-returned FID entry
var firstFID

new PerformanceObserver((entryList) => {
  for (const entry of entryList.getEntries()) {
    firstFID = entry.processingStart - entry.startTime;
  }
}).observe({type: 'first-input', buffered: true});

//Calculate CLS
clsValue = 0;
clsEntries = [];

sessionValue = 0;
sessionEntries = [];

new PerformanceObserver((entryList) => {
  for (const entry of entryList.getEntries()) {
    // Only count layout shifts without recent user input.
    if (!entry.hadRecentInput) {
      const firstSessionEntry = sessionEntries[0];
      const lastSessionEntry = sessionEntries[sessionEntries.length - 1];

      // If the entry occurred less than 1 second after the previous entry and
      // less than 5 seconds after the first entry in the session, include the
      // entry in the current session. Otherwise, start a new session.
      if (sessionValue &&
          entry.startTime - lastSessionEntry.startTime < 1000 &&
          entry.startTime - firstSessionEntry.startTime < 5000) {
        sessionValue += entry.value;
        sessionEntries.push(entry);
      } else {
        sessionValue = entry.value;
        sessionEntries = [entry];
      }

      // If the current session value is larger than the current CLS value,
      // update CLS and the entries contributing to it.
      if (sessionValue > clsValue) {
        clsValue = sessionValue;
        clsEntries = sessionEntries;

        // Log the updated value (and its entries) to the console.
        console.log('CLS:', clsValue, clsEntries)
      }
    }
  }
}).observe({type: 'layout-shift', buffered: true});


//Output values
console.log('DNS', dns);
console.log('TCP', tcp);
console.log('SSL', ssl);
console.log('firstByte', firstByte);
console.log('onload', onload);
console.log('load', load);
console.log('redirect', redirect);
console.log('basepage', basepage);
console.log('LCP', firstLCP);
console.log('FCP', fcp);
console.log('FID', firstFID);
console.log('CLS', clsValue);
```

What happens is that I get accurate values for everything *except* CLS, which returns a zero.

I suspect what is happening is that the code blasts asynchronously through everything, so the script actually ends before the final CLS value is reported.

I am guessing that this may require a promise somehow, but haven't dealt much with those and thus have no idea how to properly structure the overall code segment for that, can anyone with a lot of async experience give me any tips please?

Comment: consider changing `clsValue = 0;` to `let clsValue = 0;` or `var clsValue = 0;`; same for `clsEntries `

Comment: I would also suggest you set up proper variables rather than rely on the hoisting going on inside the conditional `if (time) {
    var dns = time.domainLookupEnd - time.domainLookupStart;`

Comment: You need to revise this; perhaps significantly, and rethink your use of global variables.  You get 0 because it is only set in the observer when runs after your `console.log` and also depends on a global `sessionValue` which is set but not defined within this code block.

Comment: Appreciate the advice! Definitely learning!

How would I best stage the console.log to run after the observer?

Comment: Update, focusing just on one of the promise statements, I'm trying to do the delay until after the observer result has returned, yet I'm getting the error that "getFCP has already been declared" :

`code`
const getFCP = new PerformanceObserver((entryList) => {
    for (const entry of entryList.getEntriesByName('first-contentful-paint')) {
      console.log('FCP candidate:', entry.startTime, entry);  
    }
  }).observe({type: 'paint', buffered: true});

getFCP.then((entryList) => {
  console.log("output = ", entryList[0]);
});

`code`

Comment: Trying to follow the examples at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: I would consider a NEW question to address with NEW code on the Promise utilization here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an update with a lot of challenges fixed.  Post your code to a validation site such as [jshint.com](https://jshint.com) to see a few.

When you run it here in a browser that supports it you will see console logs - I added quite a few here to make it "chatty" a bit.

```js
var sampleTiming = window.performance.timing.navigationStart;
console.log('Sample Timing:', sampleTiming);
var suptypes = PerformanceObserver.supportedEntryTypes;
console.log("ST:", suptypes);
var time = window.performance.timing;
var dns;
var tcp;
var ssl;
var firstByte;
var onloadE;
var request;
var load;
var redirect;
var basepage;
var firstLCP;
var fcp;
var firstFID;

if (time) {
  dns = time.domainLookupEnd - time.domainLookupStart;
  tcp = time.connectEnd - time.connectStart;
  ssl = time.requestStart - time.secureConnectionStart;
  firstByte = time.responseStart - time.navigationStart;
  onloadE = time.loadEventEnd - time.loadEventStart;
  request = time.responseStart - time.requestStart;
  load = time.loadEventEnd - time.loadEventStart;
  redirect = time.redirectEnd - time.redirectStart;
  basepage = time.responseEnd - time.navigationStart;
}

//Retrieve first browser-returned LCP entry
var firstLCP;
const largestobserver = new PerformanceObserver((entryList) => {
  firstLCP = entryList.getEntries()[0].startTime;
}).observe({
  type: 'largest-contentful-paint',
  buffered: true
});


//Retrieve browser-returned FCP entry
var fcp;

const firstobserver = new PerformanceObserver((entryList) => {
  for (const entry of entryList.getEntriesByName('first-contentful-paint')) {
    fcp = entry.startTime;
  }
}).observe({
  type: 'paint',
  buffered: true
});


//Retrieve browser-returned FID entry
var firstFID;

const firstinputobserver = new PerformanceObserver((entryList) => {
  for (const entry of entryList.getEntries()) {
    firstFID = entry.processingStart - entry.startTime;
  }
}).observe({
  type: 'first-input',
  buffered: true
});

//Calculate CLS
var clsValue = 0;
var clsValueTest = 0;
var clsEntries = [];

var sessionValue = 0;
var sessionEntries = [];

const layoutshiftobserver = new PerformanceObserver((entryList) => {
  console.log("here");
  for (const entry of entryList.getEntries()) {
    console.log("LSe:", entry);
    // Only count layout shifts without recent user input.
    if (!entry.hadRecentInput) {
      clsValueTest += entry.value;
      console.log("CTest:", clsValueTest);
      const firstSessionEntry = sessionEntries[0];
      const lastSessionEntry = sessionEntries[sessionEntries.length - 1];

      // If the entry occurred less than 1 second after the previous entry and
      // less than 5 seconds after the first entry in the session, include the
      // entry in the current session. Otherwise, start a new session.
      if (sessionValue &&
        entry.startTime - lastSessionEntry.startTime < 1000 &&
        entry.startTime - firstSessionEntry.startTime < 5000) {
        sessionValue += entry.value;
        sessionEntries.push(entry);
      } else {
        sessionValue = entry.value;
        sessionEntries = [entry];
      }

      // If the current session value is larger than the current CLS value,
      // update CLS and the entries contributing to it.
      if (sessionValue > clsValue) {
        clsValue = sessionValue;
        clsEntries = sessionEntries;

        // Log the updated value (and its entries) to the console.
        console.log('CLS:', clsValue, clsEntries);
      }
    }
  }
}).observe({
  type: 'layout-shift',
  buffered: true
});

// some of these have no values since nothing fired before this point to put anything in them.
//Output values
console.log('DNS', dns);
console.log('TCP', tcp);
console.log('SSL', ssl);
console.log('firstByte', firstByte);
console.log('onload', onloadE);
console.log('load', load);
console.log('redirect', redirect);
console.log('basepage', basepage);
console.log('LCP', firstLCP);
console.log('FCP', fcp);
console.log('FID', firstFID);
console.log('CLS', clsValue);
```

```css
div {
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="tester">fun stuff</div>
<input type="text">
<button type="button" id="fun-guys">DO IT</button>
```